# Check data before update oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask help on coding this.

I would like to check the data for this entry first before I do an update, otherwise do nothing.
Example:

```
first_name   last_name   salary    dept_no
John         Smith        5000     1

If salary = 5000 and dept_no = 1 where last_name = 'Smith' 
and first_name = 'John',
 do nothing 
else update table and set salary = 5000 and dept_no = 1 
 where last_name = 'Smith' 
 and    first_name = 'John'
```

In other words,if the data is already set to this value do nothing otherwise update the data.

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: :requirement looking abrupt ,when you have data in the table do nothing else update ?.Rather you should have like if data exist do update else insert ...correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
update <table>
set salary = 5000 and dept_no = 1 
where last_name = 'Smith' 
and    first_name = 'John'
   and salary != 5000 
   and dept_no != 1
```

Comment: Hi thanks but is there a way to do this in if else then statement plsql code?

Comment: @mysticfalls: This is the most efficient way to do this.. why do u want to do it in PLSQL?